# Ionic facebook login: getting this app is still in development mode While I set it in live mode

Tags: ionic-framework, facebook-login

I am developing an ionic app. Used facebook login, I set my facebook app into live mode, my app is running as a charm on website, but on my android device it is giving the well known error (this app is still in development mode ...). I have no facebook data access except the default public data and email, which, as I know, do not need app review.

I have double checked app id, app secret from firebase. But I am wondering if it could be because of an error in the key hash.
I have 24 or more tabs opened on my chrome searchin for the same error, all of such cases have not set the app into live mode.
[image: This image could help]

[image: This is another image that may help]
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The app is live.

I have checked every thing, and everything was correct, facebook app id in packages.json is the same as in the facebook console. (It was different and I have corrected it earlier).

I found the old facebook-app-id in the files platforms\android\android.json and platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\facebookconnect.xml.
Changed it to the actual facebook app id.